# Spin elements instead of sliding from off the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've currently got the square boxes sliding in from each side from off the page. I want the square boxes to spin while sliding into the page. Then have it stop spinning once it has got the correct position on the page.

What would be the best way of achieving the spinning?

```js
$('.box-wrapper').each(function(index, element) {

    setTimeout(function(){
        element.classList.remove('loading');
    }, index * 600);

});
```

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.box-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms;
    transition-duration: 600ms;
}

.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(odd) { transform: translate(100%) }
.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(even) { transform: translate(-100%) }


.box-wrapper:nth-child(odd)  .box { background: orange }
.box-wrapper:nth-child(even) .box { background: red }


.box {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-wrapper loading"><div class="box"></div></div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading"><div class="box"></div></div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading"><div class="box"></div></div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading"><div class="box"></div></div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading"><div class="box"></div></div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading"><div class="box"></div></div>
```

Comment: Spinning as in rotating horizontally or vertically and from where? A bit more clarity could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change this part of your code

```
.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(odd) { transform: translate(100%) }
.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(even) { transform: translate(-100%) }
```

to this

```
.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(odd) { transform: translate(100%) rotate(-180deg); }
.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(even) { transform: translate(-100%) rotate(180deg);}
```

```js
$('.box-wrapper').each(function(index, element) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.remove('loading');
  }, index * 600);

});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.box-wrapper {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
}
.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(odd) {
  transform: translate(100%) rotate(-180deg);
}
.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(even) {
  transform: translate(-100%) rotate(180deg);
}
.box-wrapper:nth-child(odd) .box {
  background: orange
}
.box-wrapper:nth-child(even) .box {
  background: red
}
.box {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, exactly what I needed :)